# subscribing to an event bus

Tags: java, guava

I am trying to use guava for subscribing to EventBus. Trying to look at the site doc but unable to see any example where it shows how to do it.

Anyone tried this before??

```
private final EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
eventBus.post(eventId); // where eventId is a string.
```

This is being in one of the jars. Now I need to subscribe to this eventbus and check if there are any new eventId's posted. How can I do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need some object with a method annotated `@Subscribe` that takes a parameter of type `String` (since you're posting a `String` as an event to it... note that some more specific event type is probably preferable). You then need to pass that object to the [EventBus.register(Object)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html#register%28java.lang.Object%29) method. Example:

```
public class Foo {
  @Subscribe
  public void handleEvent(String eventId) {
    // do something
  }
}

Foo foo = ...
eventBus.register(foo);
eventBus.post(eventId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo.

```
public class EventBusDemo{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    handleTransaction();
}

public static void handleTransaction() {
    CatSubscriber catSubscriber = new CatSubscriber();
    PandaSubscriber pandaSubscriber = new PandaSubscriber();
    DogSubscriber dogSubscriber = new DogSubscriber();
    EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
    Animal cat = new Cat();
    Animal dog = new Dog();
    Animal panda = new Panda();
    eventBus.register(pandaSubscriber);
    eventBus.register(catSubscriber);
    eventBus.register(dogSubscriber);

    eventBus.post(cat);
    eventBus.post(dog);
    eventBus.post(panda);

}
```

}

interface Animal {

```
void run();
```

}

class Cat implements Animal {

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(Cat.class.getSimpleName() + " run");
}
```

}

class CatSubscriber {

```
@Subscribe
public void catRun(Animal animal) {
    animal.run();
}
```

}

class Dog implements Animal {

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(Dog.class.getSimpleName() + " run");
}
```

}

class DogSubscriber {

```
@Subscribe
public void dogRun(Animal animal) {
    animal.run();

}
```

}

class Panda implements Animal {

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(Panda.class.getSimpleName() + " run");
}
```

}

class PandaSubscriber {

```
@Subscribe
public void pandaRun(Animal animal) {
    animal.run();
}
```

}

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.